# gnu screen: reordering windows like browser drag+drop tab reordering

Tags: gnu-screen

I have 20 windows open in my screen session, and I would like to reorder the right-most window 20 to say, just between positions 9 and 10 like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9      10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
                                                   ...V
                                        ............
                      ...................
                    ...
                    V
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  20  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

How can I do that in a single or few command/s?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how to reorder the window number using mouse. But in git version, window number can increase or decrease relative amount.

`number [[+|-]n]`

And in the `windowlist`, you can swap the window number using `,`(previous) or `.`(next).

In your example, the following procedure would satisfy your wishes.

1. select the window you want to move(`select 20`)
2. switch into windowlist(`windowlist`)
3. type `,` key 10 times
4. (exit windowlist)

Comment: does this work for an existing screen session that I reconnected with the git version using 'screen -RD'?

Comment: I think probably not. This feature require newer version both FRONTEND screen and BACKEND screen.

Comment: This is what I thought. I'll start a new one with the git version once the one I have running needs to be closed... Thanks!

Comment: Perfect answer..  worked like a charm.  Just a hint..  to get the windowlist, press CTRL+a-" .

Comment: This doesn't work in screen 4.

Answer (score 21):

The best I know of, is to re-number all your windows, like this:

```
C-a :number X
```

where C = ctrl, and X is the number your want for this window. In your case, this means that you need to move 20 -> 10, and 10 -> 20. Use a more complicated approach if you prefer.

From the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/):

```
  number [n]

   Change  the  current  windows  number. If the given number n is already
   used by another window, both windows  exchange  their  numbers.  If  no
   argument  is specified, the current window number (and title) is shown.
```

Comment: In screen 4.00 it is confusing to use `C-a :number x` while in `:windowlist`. It works nicely when I am in a current widow and use quick list with `C-a w` then `C-a :number x` to switch the current window, for instance to the next or previous one to emulate @yoshikaw answer.